# VPN Client implementation specific to application

Tags: android, vpn, ipsec

I wanted to implement the application specific VPN client in android, that is vpn connection once established should be only available to our application and rest of the apps in android device should make use of normal internet connection.

To elaborate my need more, i have an application already which connects to corporate email, files and other data from internet normally but for some security reason we need it to be go through tunnel within our application and access everything within via tunnel basically want we are looking here is security while accessing company corporate network.

Since we are new to something like this we don't have a hint on how to start what protocols to use etc (we are assuming ipsec l2tp for now), any information, hint or redirects to useful resource will be really helpful.

And between we are just looking to send and receive data over tunnel, there is nothing more or need to control computer on the network all we need is to route data through corporate firewall and should support multiple vpn servers such as cisco, microsoft etc. Can any one say how complex or how feasible to implement it.

Manjunath

Answer (score 1):

As your question comprises of several parts so i will start putting my input one by one on each of them.

> I wanted to implement the application specific VPN client in android,
>   that is vpn connection once established should be only available to
>   our application and rest of the apps in android device should make use
>   of normal internet connection.

This is the case of split tunneling and i don't think that there is any personal vpn provider that offers such feature in android app / phone. However, it does not mean that their is no solution for your query. CISO client Juniper SA2500 SSL VPN Appliance split tunnels has this feature which allow android users to work through split tunnel which enable them to route the traffic through different channels. 
You just need to Just go to  Roles > Network Connect Role, then Split Tunneling Options and disable split tunnel.

Or> Push" the proxy settings so the web traffic is diverted to the proxy via the tunnel as the end user will no longer be able to go the the Internet directly:
Users --> Resources Policies --> Network Connect --> NC Connection Profiles then filter for the role bound to your NC enabled realm. Make sure that under the "Proxy Server Settings" section

Elsewhere, there is another client named as QuickSec VPN 2.0 which also enables user with split tunneling.

And for all such things SSL VPN Connection is the most reliable one as it is feature with strong encryption and security.

The split tunneling concept for Personal VPN has been introduced by well stabled VPN providers like PureVPN and Ivacy which has described the concept of split tunneling through their client software.

Answer (score 0):

Go for SSL connection it is as good as Tunneling if you just wanted to exchange packets, integrating a VPN Solution within you application will become another project which is not recommend and takes time.